# New to macos: Apple Ventura OS will not let me delete TV?

Tags: terminal, appletv, macos

I want to delete Apple TV on my 14-inch 2021 Macbook Pro M1, Ventura OS 13.1 version.

Running the command `sudo rm -Rdf /System/Applications/TV.app` in my terminal returns "Operation not permitted". I have also tried dragging the app from the Applications folder to the bin without success, and if I right-click there is no 'Move to Bin' option.

This is my first Mac after using Linux for many years and it is very frustrating that I am the owner of a computer that will not let me make my own decisions. This is potentially a deal-breaker for me.

Any help to solve this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple introduced a [Signed System Volume](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/) with Big Sur in 2020. Basically this means that

- macOS is installed on its own volume/partition
- This volume is mounted read-only at boot time
- There is a cryptographic hash created for each file on the volume
- These hashes are "aggregated" up over the whole volume (with a [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree)) into a volume seal
- The seal is checked at boot time, the system will not boot if the seal is broken/the content of the volume has changed

The whole mechanism ensures that the system volume with the OS can not be tampered with by malware and similar.

To change the content of the system volume nevertheless, you can

- boot into recovery
- turn cryptographic verification off
- change whatever needs changing
- reseal the volume to make it bootable again

Details on how to do this are in the article linked at the beginning. Be aware that you will need to do this after each OS update.

PS: If your main concern is the `TV` folder in `~/Movies`: `chflags hidden ~/Movies/TV` hides it from Finder.

Comment: chflags hidden ~/Movies/TV really helped in hiding the unwanted TV folder